# Tasked to create an Undo button in C#

Tags: c#

it's my first post here. I'm learning C# (visual studio) at the moment and we have been building a program through given tasks. The last task is to create an "undo" button. This is the code so far:

```
namespace GestBar_v1._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string[] bebidas = { "Café", "Ice Tea", "Água", "Aguardente" };
        double[] precoBebidas = { 0.8, 1.5, 1.0, 1.0 };

        string[] alimentacao = { "Bolos", "Sandes Mistas", "Torrada", "Salgados" };
        double[] precoAlimentacao = { 1.0, 1.5, 1.5, 1.0 };

        double soma = 0;
        double fecho = 0;

        void resetTxt()
        {
            txtPreco.BackColor = Color.White;
            txtPreco.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            txtPreco.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            label2.Text = "Preço Final";
        }

        private void Processo(string[] items, double[] prices, int itemIndex)
        {
            if (listaProduto.Items.Contains(items[itemIndex]))
            {
                int index = listaProduto.Items.IndexOf(items[itemIndex]);
                double count = double.Parse(listaUnidade.Items[index].ToString());
                listaPreco.Items[index] = Math.Round(prices[itemIndex] * (count + 1), 2);
                listaUnidade.Items[index] = count + 1;
                soma += prices[itemIndex];
            }
            else
            {
                listaProduto.Items.Add(items[itemIndex]);
                listaPreco.Items.Add(prices[itemIndex]);
                listaUnidade.Items.Add(1);
                soma += prices[itemIndex];
            }
            txtPreco.Text = soma.ToString();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();

            btn11.Visible = true;
            btn12.Visible = true;
            btn13.Visible = true;
            btn14.Visible = true;

            btn11.Text = bebidas[0] + "\n" + precoBebidas[0] + "€";
            btn12.Text = bebidas[1] + "\n" + precoBebidas[1] + "€";
            btn13.Text = bebidas[2] + "\n" + precoBebidas[2] + "€";
            btn14.Text = bebidas[3] + "\n" + precoBebidas[3] + "€";

            btn21.Visible = false;
            btn22.Visible = false;
            btn23.Visible = false;
            btn24.Visible = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAliment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();

            btn21.Visible = true;
            btn22.Visible = true;
            btn23.Visible = true;
            btn24.Visible = true;

            btn21.Text = alimentacao[0] + "\n" + precoAlimentacao[0] + "€";
            btn22.Text = alimentacao[1] + "\n" + precoAlimentacao[1] + "€";
            btn23.Text = alimentacao[2] + "\n" + precoAlimentacao[2] + "€";
            btn24.Text = alimentacao[3] + "\n" + precoAlimentacao[3] + "€";

            btn11.Visible = false;
            btn12.Visible = false;
            btn13.Visible = false;
            btn14.Visible = false;

        }

        private void btnTodosP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();

            btn11.Visible = true;
            btn12.Visible = true;
            btn13.Visible = true;
            btn14.Visible = true;

            btn21.Visible = true;
            btn22.Visible = true;
            btn23.Visible = true;
            btn24.Visible = true;

            btn11.Text = bebidas[0] + "\n" + precoBebidas[0] + "€";
            btn12.Text = bebidas[1] + "\n" + precoBebidas[1] + "€";
            btn13.Text = bebidas[2] + "\n" + precoBebidas[2] + "€";
            btn14.Text = bebidas[3] + "\n" + precoBebidas[3] + "€";

            btn21.Text = alimentacao[0] + "\n" + precoAlimentacao[0] + "€";
            btn22.Text = alimentacao[1] + "\n" + precoAlimentacao[1] + "€";
            btn23.Text = alimentacao[2] + "\n" + precoAlimentacao[2] + "€";
            btn24.Text = alimentacao[3] + "\n" + precoAlimentacao[3] + "€";

        }

        private void btn11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();
            Processo(bebidas, precoBebidas, 0);
        }

        private void btn12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();
            Processo(bebidas, precoBebidas, 1);
        }
            private void btn13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();
            Processo(bebidas, precoBebidas, 2);
        }

        private void btn14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();
            Processo(bebidas, precoBebidas, 3);
        }

        private void btn21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();
            Processo(alimentacao, precoAlimentacao, 0);
        }

        private void btn22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();
            Processo(alimentacao, precoAlimentacao, 1);
        }

        private void btn23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();
            Processo(alimentacao, precoAlimentacao, 2);
        }

        private void btn24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();
            Processo(alimentacao, precoAlimentacao, 3);
        }

        private void btnNovo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTxt();
            fecho += Convert.ToDouble(txtPreco.Text);
            listaProduto.Items.Clear();
            listaPreco.Items.Clear();
            listaUnidade.Items.Clear();
            txtPreco.Clear();
            soma = 0;
        }

        private void btnRetirarSelec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listaProduto.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                int index = listaProduto.SelectedIndex;
                double count = double.Parse(listaUnidade.Items[index].ToString());
                soma -= count * precoBebidas[index];
                listaUnidade.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                listaPreco.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                listaProduto.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                txtPreco.Text = soma.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void btnReduzQnt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = -1;
            if (listaProduto.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                index = listaProduto.SelectedIndex;
            }
            else if (listaPreco.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                index = listaPreco.SelectedIndex;
            }
            else if (listaUnidade.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                index = listaUnidade.SelectedIndex;
            }

            if (index >= 0)
            {
                double count = double.Parse(listaUnidade.Items[index].ToString());
                if (count > 1)
                {
                    soma -= precoBebidas[index];
                    soma -= precoAlimentacao[index];
                    listaUnidade.Items[index] = count - 1;
                    listaPreco.Items[index] = Math.Round(precoBebidas[index] * (count - 1), 2);
                    listaPreco.Items[index] = Math.Round(precoAlimentacao[index] * (count - 1), 2);
                    txtPreco.Text = soma.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    listaUnidade.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                    listaPreco.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                    listaProduto.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                    txtPreco.Text = soma.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnFechoC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtPreco.Text = fecho.ToString();
            txtPreco.BackColor = Color.Green;
            txtPreco.ForeColor = Color.White;
            txtPreco.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
            label2.Text = "Saldo Final";
            MessageBox.Show("A caixa foi Encerrada.");
            fecho = 0;
        }

        private void btnReturn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

    }
}
```

I'm sorry about some of the Portuguese elements in the code. Can anyone help out on how to do this? I'm completly lost on this one.

I thought of creating an array and making every button click start by saving the "status quo" to the erray and having it update the listboxes through a button. But I couldn't implement it. The fixed numbers on arrays seems to be the factor.

Comment: All logic is in the UI? This is a guarantee for failure. You absolutely need a business class object (a class that contains the full state of what seems to be some kind of vending machine). UI elements are no data containers.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be a very basic POS system.

Comment: I'm still learning, don't think I've ever learned about business class objects :\

Comment: Then please start with that: Create a separate class that contains the state of your system (we call that a business object).  In the UI, you will only display the content of that object (after each change, you would update the UI). Doing an Undo is easy then, you can just keep the last state in a copy of your business object.

Comment: I think that if OP is learning C# and Visual Studio, OP approach is valid. The approach that OP is trying to implement is somehow good directed, but the datastructure that you are using is not. Instead of going for an array, use a stack.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jazz :) Unfortunatly we haven't touched the topic of stacks aswell. So it seems that it's another tool not accessible to me. This is an humbling experience. Still lots and lots to learn.

Answer (score 0):

When you say fixed numbers on arrays, do you mean that it is a hindrance that they can only be of pre-defined sizes?

If that's the case, then use a List. First import the necessary library then create the list, both as shown below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
List<type> myList = new List<type>();
```

You can add as many items to a list without pre-defining its size.

To append items to the list use:

```
myList.Append(someData);
```

To then access the last action made by the user (which you have already appended to the list), use:

```
type lastAction = myList[-1];
```